# Display Icon and Input on same line and full width

Tags: html, css

This should be fairly simple but I'm having a hard time figuring this out.  I want the Icon and Input to be on the same line and the Input to take up the rest of the width of the line.  If I set the width:100% of the socialInput it puts them on 2 lines.  If I set it to 95% when you adjust the screen smaller it will put them on 2 lines. I want it to be on 1 line all the time no matter what the screen size is

```
<div class="socialInputRow col-12">
   <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
   <RadzenTextBox class="socialInput" Name="FacebookURL" @bind-Value="@Recipe.SocialMedia.FacebookURL" placeholder="https://www.facebook.com/" AutoComplete="false"></RadzenTextBox>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `flexbox` to the div and `flex-grow` to the input will solve this. Alternativly if all icons and input use the same warpper: `css-grid` + `grid-template-columns: min-content auto;`

Comment: can you expand on that please?

Comment: what was still unclear after researching on those hints?

Answer (score 0):

Per tacoshy

```css
.socialInputRow{
 display: flex;
}

.socialInput{
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work perfectly

```css
.socialInputRow{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```